# Is it necessary to have a robots.txt if header x-robots is set to noindex, no follow?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nofollow, noindex

I'm attempting to prevent my website from being indexed/listed:

I've set in .htaccess:

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
```

Is it also necessary to set robots.txt?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Is there any harm in adding the robots.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, if have X-Robots-Tag set, I must remove any crawl disallows in robots.txt:

> Robots meta tags and X-Robots-Tag HTTP headers are discovered when a
>   URL is crawled. If a page is disallowed from crawling through the
>   robots.txt file, then any information about indexing or serving
>   directives will not be found and will therefore be ignored. If
>   indexing or serving directives must be followed, the URLs containing
>   those directives cannot be disallowed from crawling.
>
> via: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag#combining-crawling-with-indexing--serving-directives